# Disregard the first and last number in array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a subject programming and my school teacher is not teaching us well. He gave us a task where in the program should disregard the first and last element of the array depending on the user input. My code works in the first try but if i start to run the program again it prints out the last number. I knew that my *time* variable and the condition of the second for loop is the root cause of overprinting is there any way i could fix it or do some modifications on my code. Thanks for helping.

To understand more if the user input a number 3 with max size of 3 the program should output : 4 5

if i run the program again and input the same values the program will print : 
4 5 4 5 6 
which is wrong..

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int main () 
{
        int Max[100],num,Values[100];
        int rear=0,total,input=0;  
        char choice; 

    do {

    system("cls"); 
    cout<<"\n Enter the number : ";
    cin>>num; 

    cout<<"\n Enter the Max Size: ";
    cin>>Max[rear]; 

    total = Max[rear] - 2; 

    for(int i = 0; i<rear; i++)
    {      
        total += Max[rear];
    }

        for(int i=input; i<=total; i++) 
            {
                Values[i]= ++num; 
                input++; 
            }

        cout<<"\n\n Output: "; 
        for(int i=0; i<=total; i++) 
        {

            cout<<" "<<Values[i]; 
        }

    rear++;                   
    cout<<"\n\n Run the Program Again  Y/N ? ";
    cin>>choice; 

    }while (choice=='Y' || choice=='y'); 


return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Are you saying for the inputs start = 4, size = 7 it should print the contents of array elements a[5] ... a[9] ?  Or just the numbers 5,6,7,8,9 ?  If the array contents, how are a[1] ... a[99] supposed to be set?

Comment: What do you mean by "disregard  the first and last element of the array"?

Comment: It's also a good idea to read [tour] then [ask] then [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things are at play here, and they both seem to be a result of your first for loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i<rear; i++)
{      
    total += Max[rear];
}
```

The first thing to note, is that only the value of 'Max[rear]' assigned at the current loop is compounded. This works fine if every entry is the same length, but not so much if each entry differs. so this..

```
   total += Max[rear];
```

becomes this..

```
   total += Max[i];
```

Great! But there still seems to be an overprinting problem happening?

This issue is just an *off-by-one error*, caused by the fact that your for loops tend to use <= and non-zero starting points; There's nothing wrong with that, but it can mistakes hard to catch!

When you start to compound entries from your 'Max' array onto the 'total' variable in your first for loop, they increase the variable by one more than they need to; so simply changing that same line we discussed earlier from..

```
    total += Max[i];
```

to..

```
    total += Max[i] - 1;
```

removes that offset and seems to resolve your overprinting problem nicely.

> Enter the number : 3
>
> Enter the Max Size: 3
>
> Output: 4 5 4 5

Comment: Thank you very much Brenda for detailed explanation i wish your my teacher in programming. :)